# How to suppress exception message in output window of Visual Studio 2022 (.NET Core 6)

Tags: visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

I try to suppress message about exception in the output window:

[image: extra message in Output window]

How is this possible?

Comment: If you right click on that pane, there should be several categories of output that you can toggle on and off.  Did you try those?

Comment: thank you, @Jimmy, this is temporary solution to receive list of instantiated service, but I search something deeper, maybe attributes for or something other, because I have interest to exception in other parts of my code with forbidden exception messages in current parts of code